# Obtaining $\lambda$ for a Poisson Distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

Is it possible to manipulate a Poisson Distribution's $\lambda$ value such that it has a probability mass function that looks like the curve below with data points $(8,0)$,$(7,0.01)$,$(5,0.1)$ and $(2,1)$. I have been trying to obtain a $\lambda$ that will satisfy these values but have been struggling as the probability mass function equation does not break down easily.

[image]

Comment: Only by interpreting "looks like" very loosely, as if all the probability mass is already at a strain value of 2, there's none left to go anywhere else - the probability over all values has to add up to exactly one. What is it you're really trying to do?

Comment: @Scortchi Basically, I have the graph above and I want to see what sort of probability distribution will actually fit it, as I need to check the ${\rm P}(Strain \le X_2)$ where $X_2$ is Normally Distributed. Is what I am trying to achieve feasible?

Comment: What's $X_2$ & how's it related to your graph?

Comment: @Scortchi $X_2$ is the _Minnimum Threshold Strain_. So, I want to get the graph of ${\rm P}(Strain \le Minnimum Threshold Strain)$ where _Strain_ and _Minnimum Threshold Strain_ are independant.

Comment: Which has what to do exactly with the graph you're showing of strain vs probability of loading?

Comment: @Scortchi Does this make sense? Cheers

Comment: Not to me - sorry. You can calculate either the probability of a random variable's being greater than a constant or the probability of its being greater than another random variable.  I haven't the foggiest idea which is applicable to your case, & still don't know what the graph has to do with any of that. If @Stephan's answer isn't what you wanted my advice is to take several steps back & clearly explain what it is you want to find out from what, giving enough context to make it understandable by non-psychics, & favouring layman's terms over statistical ones unless you're very sure you're ...

Comment: ... using the latter correctly. (Peter Flom's blog has some good [advice](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question) on asking statistics questions.)

Comment: @Scortchi 1)I want to determine ${\rm P}(Strain \le MinnimumThresholdStrain)$. 2) The probability plot associated with _Strain_ is shown above. (It is not a probability distribution) 3) The _MinnimumThresholdStrain_ is Normally Distributed. 4) Now, I thought that I could only find  ${\rm P}(Strain \le MinnimumThresholdStrain)$ if  ${\rm P}(Strain)$ is **also a probability distribution**. 5) I posted the original question as I thought I could obtain a Poisson _Distribution_ that looked like the graph above. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. Therefore, is it possible to find ....

Comment: @Scortchi .....${\rm P}(Strain \le MinnimumThresholdStrain)$ when ${\rm P}(Strain)$ isn't a probability Distribution? If so, could you please tell me how this is done? Thanks

Comment: Rather than throw a sequence of probability distributions at this problem (which I think is an utterly mistaken enterprise when the data is just guesses anyway), why not describe what the original underlying problem you're trying to solve is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [maximum likelihood estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Maximum_likelihood) for $\lambda$, given some observations, is just the mean of the observations. So if you do have observations, simply average them.

Your probabilities do not add up to one. You can take the weighted mean of (8, 7, 5, 2) with your weights (0,0.01,0.1,1), which yields 2.32. The corresponding probability mass function will look like this (R code underneath):
[image]

```
lambda <- weighted.mean(c(7,5,2),w=c(0.01,0.1,1))
xx <- seq(0,8,by=1)
foo <- barplot(dpois(xx,lambda))
axis(1,foo[,1],xx)
```

This does not look much like your plot. You may want to consider overdispersion and try modeling your data using a negative binomial distribution.